# How do you find if a record exists?

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, vba

```
Dim mydb As DAO.Database
Dim myrst As DAO.Recordset
Dim Date1, Date2 As Date
Dim mysql As String
Dim qdf As QueryDef
Dim EmployeeID As String

    EmployeeID = DLookup("lngEmpID", "tblEmployees", "Forms!frmEmployeeOrderForm.cboEmployeeName.Value = EmployeeName")
    Me.EmpID = EmployeeID
    PickupTime = DLookup("Pickup", "tblEmployees", "Forms!frmEmployeeOrderForm.cboEmployeeName.Value = EmployeeName")
    Me.PickupDay = PickupTime

    Set mydb = CurrentDb
    Date1 = Me.dtmGiveAwayDate1
    Date2 = Me.dtmGiveAwayDate2
    mysql = ("Select tblOrders.lngEmpID, tblOrders.dtmGiveAwayDate1, tblOrders.dtmGiveAwayDate2 FROM tblOrders WHERE tblOrders.lngEmpID =" & EmployeeID & " AND tblOrders.dtmGiveAwayDate1 =" & Date1 & " AND tblOrders.dtmGiveAwayDate2 =" & Date2)
    MsgBox mysql
    Set myrst = mydb.OpenRecordset(mysql)

    If myrst.EOF = False Then
        MsgBox "You have already ordered for this PFG." & vbCrLf & "Please see Jody for help."
        cmdCancel_Click
        Exit Sub
    End If
```

When I run the program I am trying to prevent employees from entering their name twice for the same dates. To test I tried to duplicate a record for the same employee and it will not trigger the myrst.eof = false and display the message box that says "You have already ordered for this PFG". Any help is much appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This returns 0 records. But if I surround the dates in # signs then it returns the record I am looking for. How do I put those into my code? When I try I get an error.

Answer (score 0):

Use the FindFirst method :

```
myrst.FindFirst "field = " & value

If myrst.NoMatch Then
      //code when record doesn't exist       
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Checking for equality with dates can be tricky.  Since VBA dates can include time to the nanosecond, could it be that one side (SQL/code) has a real time, while the other has the default midnight value?

Comment: Select tblOrders.lngEmpID, tblOrders.dtmGiveAwayDate1, tblOrders.dtmGiveAwayDate2 FROM tblOrders WHERE tblOrders.lngEmpID = 200832 AND tblOrders.dtmGiveAwayDate1 = 8/17/2015 AND tblOrders.dtmGiveAwayDate2 = 8/18/2015

Comment: Above is the sql code that the program spits out. The dates are formatted as short dates in the table. I'm not sure what is going on

Comment: I see below you got it!  Nice. Sorry I couldn't remember the vba side of formatting dates when I posted that yesterday, I'm glad you got it figured out.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Set mydb = CurrentDb
    Date1 = Format(Me.dtmGiveAwayDate1, "Short Date")
    Date2 = Format(Me.dtmGiveAwayDate2, "Short Date")
    mysql = ("Select tblOrders.lngEmpID, tblOrders.dtmGiveAwayDate1, tblOrders.dtmGiveAwayDate2 FROM tblOrders WHERE tblOrders.lngEmpID =" & EmployeeID & " AND tblOrders.dtmGiveAwayDate1 =" & "#" & Date1 & "#" & " AND tblOrders.dtmGiveAwayDate2 =" & "#" & Date2 & "#")
    MsgBox mysql
    Set myrst = mydb.OpenRecordset(mysql)
```

This was the code I used and it works now. Thank you.